# How to pass multiple dependencies object to controller constructor while doing unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq

I have a controller in which there are multiple dependencies.And i have made a parameter constructor for that controller,which is taking the object of one of the main dependency(service layer).

```
 public class ProductController 
 {

       private IProductService _productService ;
       public ProductController(IProductService productService)
       {
           this._productService = productService;
       }
  }
```

But in controller there are some methods which are working with multiple dependencies.

```
   Public ActionResult GetProductDetails()
   {
        List<CategoryDto> catList = CategoryService.GetAllCategories()).ToList();

        ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
        {
           Name="",
           Categories = catList
       };
       //other stuffs...

   }
```

> > In the above method there is a different dependency CategoryService.And i want to ask to mock that dependency should i need to make different constructor or can i pass multiple dependency object to same constructor ?

Comment: Your injectables should [always have just a single constructor](https://bit.ly/1qhGMlw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inject all dependencies to class you are testing (SUT). You can use constructor or property injection. I would go with constructor injection:

```
 public class ProductController 
 {
       private IProductService productService;
       private ICategoryService categoryService;

       public ProductController(IProductService productService, 
                                ICategoryService categoryService)
       {
           this.productService = productService;
           this.categoryService = categoryService;
       }

       public ActionResult GetProductDetails()
       {
           var categories = categoryService.GetAllCategories().ToList();
           // ...
       }
  }
```

In your tests you can use setup method (NUnit syntax) to create and pass mocked dependencies to SUT:

```
  private ProductController controller;
  private Mock<IProductService> productServiceMock;
  private Mock<ICategoryService> categoryServiceMock;


  [SetUp]
  public void Setup()
  {
      productServiceMock = new Mock<IProductService>();
      categoryServiceMock = new Mock<ICategoryService>();
      controller = new ProductController(productServiceMock.Object,
                                         categoryServiceMock.Object);
  }
```

Then you can arrange any of this mocked object in test methods, just before exercising SUT:

```
  [Test]
  public void ShouldReturnProductDetails()
  {
      List<CategoryDto> categories = // ...
      categoryServiceMock.Setup(cs => cs.GetAllCategories()).Returns(categories);

      var result = controller.GetProductDetails();
      // Assert
  }
```

Comment: its looks needful @Sergey

Comment: is there any online support to get knowledge about unit testing ? Or can i communicate directly ?

Comment: @Pawan: Have you tried [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for knowledge about unit testing? :-)

Comment: this site @Steven located to Stackoverflow.Are you asking about it ?

Comment: @Pawan: What I meant was you can always ask here at Stackoverflow. The best resource about Unit Testing I know of is [this book by Roy Osherove](http://www.manning.com/osherove2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the service locate pattern: the controller use a service locator to get service instances.

in the constructor:

```
public class ProductController 
 {
       private IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;


       public ProductController(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
       {
           _serviceLocator= serviceLocator;
       }
  }
```

when you want to use a certain service:

```
ICategoryService categoryService = _serviceLocator.GetService(typeof(categoryService))
```

MSDN has an article: [The Service Locator Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) which explain whey use this pattern.

Comment: And here is another article by Mark Seemann which explains [why Service Locator anti-pattern should be avoided](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: -1, because -as @SergeyBerezovskiy said- this is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: @Steven there's a lot of discussion regards that if the service locator pattern is an anti pattern or not.

Comment: @Matt: Sure, but in my opinion it IS an anti-pattern and I therefore highly disagree with your answer. To communicate this to anyone reading this question, I flagged your answer with -1.